# Minimum height of a mechitza

Tags: tefillah-betzibbur, mechitza-partition

Is anyone aware of a halachic opinion that permits, l'hatchilah, a mechitza of ten tefachim?  I'm familiar with talmudic sources and with the normative debate (shoulder height vs. higher) and the issue of sight vs. separation. I've also heard that Rav Soloveitchik permitted it under extenuating circumstances in at least one case.  But does anyone know of an opinion that says ten tefachim ought to be acecptable?

Answer (score 1):

(In your first sentence you write that you are asking about l'hatchilah, but in your last sentence you write "ought to be acceptable" which seems to imply some level of b'diavad. So I will post this answer even though it is not l'hatchilah.)

[R. Joseph Elijah Henkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Eliyahu_Henkin) mentions 10 tefachim in a responsum to R. Shraga Feivel Greenstein.

**Shu"t Gevurot Eliyahu 1:44**

> **א.** בודאי הצדק אתו שראוי לעשות מחיצה כהוגן של עשרה טפחים לפחות ולמעלה ווילון ואף שלפעמים מפשילין הווילון הוא דבר ארעי ואין חוששין לו
>   אבל בוילון כלשהו מלמעלה שלאחר שמפשילין אותו לא נשאר כלל מחיצה לא נכון
>   כלל וכת"ר יעשה בחכמה לתקן הדבר בהמשך השמן ובכל זה כיון שיש איזה ווילון
>   והם טוענים שעשו ע"פ רבנים אין לו לכת"ר להתפטר עצמו מהרבנות בגלל זה
>   וינהג עמהם במקל נועם
>
> **1.** He is certainly correct that it is proper to make a proper mechitzah of at least 10 tefachim with a curtain above. And even
>   though at times they pull aside the curtain, this is a temporary thing
>   and we are not concerned with it. But if [the mechitza] is entirely
>   curtain from the top, such that when they pull it aside there is no
>   mechitzah remaining, it is not at all proper. The Honor of His Torah
>   should act with wisdom to correct the matter as time goes on. And with
>   all this, since there is a curtain of some sort and they claim that
>   this was done with rabbis, The Honor of His Torah should not recuse
>   himself from the rabbinate on account of this, and he should act with
>   them leniently.
>
> **ב.** שיעור המחיצה אם אפשר יהא כגוף בינוני עד הראש ובשעת הדחק תהיה המחיצה לפחות עשרה טפחים ולמעלה מזה יהא ווילון מספיק וזה עדיף מווילון
>   מן הקרקע עד למעלה
>
> **2.** The measurement for a mechitzah if possible should be like the body of an average person up to the head. In pressing circumstances
>   the mechitza should be at least 10 tefachim with a sufficient curtain
>   on top. This is better than a curtain from the ground to the top.

Comment: Is the main purpose of the mechitzah to avoid seeing or avoid interacting? If the first, then why were balconies more common in older larger shuls for so many years, when you can still see the women?

Comment: There is a machlokes achronim whether a mechitzah made from glass - where the women are still visible is acceptable. The question is whether we simply need a separation or for them not to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you consider acceptable for your situation, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechitza) entry quotes,

> Modern Orthodox Rabbi Ahron Soloveichik, a mechitzah need only serve
>   as a halakhic partition, and hence need only be the minimum height for
>   such a partition. Rabbi Soloveichik holds that this height is 10
>   tefachim,(each "tefach" 3.2 inches) about 32 inches is acceptable.[10]

Additionally, [this](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v61/mj_v61i58.html) exchange records,

> I was a Hillel director from 1980 to 1987 in rural Rhode Island at the
>   state university, away from the state's Jewish population.  As a
>   result, we attracted students with minimal Jewish identity.   In
>   addition, there was a little synagogue near the campus that had in its
>   constitution that it had to be Orthodox (there was only one, part time
>   Orthodox family member) but there was confusion as to what kind of and
>   how high the mehiza needed to be.  So I asked that Rav for his views.
>
> As to the University, he said that 40" high would be acceptable.  If
>   you say one tefah equals 4", then a ten tefahim mehiza would be 40"
>   tall.   As to the synagogue, he ruled 44" tall (maybe this was 11
>   tefahim tall?).

Comment: This is useful. The second more than the second (and you should clarify it speaks of R Yosef Dor Soloveichik). But I tried to track the first reference and didn't find it originally. [This](http://etzion.org.il/en/separation-during-prayer-mechitza) article says it is in [Tradition](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimer2-1.htm) but that doesn't appear to be the case. Would be useful to find one real reference beyond Wikipedia (which can be inexact). Makes the second reference all the more useful

Comment: thank you for this.  i had the same problem - i saw references to the soloveichik position of 10 tefachim but found no written sournce.  I had not read about the university/shul distinction. thanks